# need clarification on malloc

Tags: c

I have following code, on 64 bit linux, kernel 2.6.x. As far my understanding goes, the first malloc `rrr=malloc(8)`, allocates 8 bytes on a heap and rrr now contains the value of the starting address of those 8 bytes. Then, i do something crazy. i try to store a 8byte pointer in a single byte as shown in `*rrr = malloc(8)`. Then i do the same at 5th byte. A single byte can only hold values upto 255, but when i print the values stored in these bytes, the values are bigger than 255. can you please explain it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ** rrr;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rrr = malloc(8); // rrr should point to the starting address of an 8 byte block
  *rrr = malloc(8);
  *(rrr+5) = malloc(8);

  for(int i =0;i< 8;i++)
    printf("*rrr%d: %p\n", i, *(rrr+i)); // should print what is stored in each byte

 return 0;
}
```

One run of above returns

```
*rrr0: 0x9ae030
*rrr1: (nil)
*rrr2: (nil)
*rrr3: 0x21
*rrr4: (nil)
*rrr5: 0x9ae050
*rrr6: (nil)
*rrr7: 0x21
```

Comment: I'm slightly curious, because your pointer values look suspiciously like they are 32-bit pointers. Now, I could be wrong, but I think your code is 32-bit, not 64-bit, in which case your pointers are 4 bytes. Doesn't change the essence of the answers given below, of course.

Comment: sizeof(void *) is 8 on my machine

Comment: Ok, your heap must just happen to be in a fairly low memory location, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A single byte can only hold values upto 255, but when i print the
>   values stored in these bytes, the values are bigger than 255

But `*rrr` is a `void *`, which is probably 8 bytes on your machine and able to hold any object pointer by definition.

Also, since you only allocated 8 bytes to `rrr`, anything past the first element - assignments or reads - is illegal.

---

You seem to be under the impression that allocating 8 bytes will somehow distribute them evenly between elements, which is not the case. After the allocation `rrr` points to 8 bytes which you can use, and you do so using `*rrr = malloc...`. This is all correct and expected: `*rrr` is a void, thus able to hold any address, thus able to hold things larger than 255 which you mentioned.

The minute you go to `rrr + 1` or further you're stepping in undefined behavior and unexpected things will happen.

#### EDIT

> but i contest the point that if i print each byte value of an 8 byte
>   block, that any byte can hold value > 255

But you're not printing bytes! You're printing pointers and adding `i` to `rrr` **advances it to the next pointer**.

Comment: how do you explain *rrr0 containing value higher than 255 and *rrr1 is nill ?

Comment: @Jimm Like I said. Your assumption that `void *` is 1 byte wide is wrong. It's most likely 4/8 bytes wide, thus amply able to store values larger than 255.

Comment: why? would you agree that my first malloc (rrr = malloc(8)) created 8 bytes on a heap?

Comment: @Jimm I only agree `malloc` allocates 8 bytes, which you are allowed to use. Everything else you use is subject to undefined behavior.

Comment: ok if you agree that malloc allocated 8 bytes, how can you explain the printf , where first byte contains value > 255?

Comment: I agree with everything you said with rrr+1, but i contest the point that if i print each byte value of an 8 byte block, that any byte can hold value > 255. A byte  is only 8 bits on my machine

Comment: @Jimm Okay, you seem to have a wrong idea about pointer arithmetic. I edited one more time but you should probably review how that works and then you'll get it.

Comment: how do i print each byte's value in that 8 byte block?

Comment: @Jimm Cast to a `char *p` and then print `p[0], p[1]..`.

Comment: sizeof(char *) is 8 also. and p[0] == *(p+0) and p[1] == *(p+1) correct? In this case wouldnt *(p+1) print the value in byte starting from 9th byte?

Comment: @Jimm Adding 1 to a pointer increases the address **by the size of the pointed type**, not by the size of the pointer itself. So adding 1 to `p` increases its address by the size of char, which is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 1):

> i try to store a 8byte pointer in a single byte

There are no single bytes in your code.  `rrr` is a pointer, and so is `*rrr` (because you declared `rrr` as a pointer-to-pointer).

However, you're almost certainly invoking **undefined behaviour** here.  Unless `sizeof(void *)` is 1 (which is extremely unlikely!), then writing to `*(rrr+5)` will be writing beyond the bounds of the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Since `rrr` is a `void**`, `rrr+5` points 40 bytes into the 8-byte memory you allocated, since  `sizeof(void *) == 8` on a 64-bit linux machine.

Whenever you add an integer to a pointer in C, the integer is always scaled by (multiplied by) the size of whatever the pointer points at (`sizeof(*rrr)` here, which is `sizeof(void *)`)

Comment: how do you explain *rrr0: 0x9ae030, which is > 255

Comment: @Jimm: `*(rrr+i)` reads 8 bytes from the address i*8 bytes after that pointed at by `rrr`.  The 8 comes from `sizeof(void *)`.